# Позиционирование вложенных div CSS

Tags: css, html

Есть родительский div. 
Внутри него у меня находятся множество других div с атрибутом position:relative. У них разные отступы top и left.

Я не могу понять почему позиции некоторых таких вложенных div отсчитываются от верхнего левого края родительского div, а какие то вдруг от середины этого родительского div? Хотя свойства у них одинаковые..
Если изменить top на отрицательные значения, то получается спозиционировать. 
Код родительского div:

```
.tableOverLO {position: relative; width:1156; height:822; background: url(LOnew.png); border-radius: 150px; border: solid;}
```

Ниже вложенные в родительский (их несколько, разница только в top и left):

```
.viborg {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 190; left: 170; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
.priozersk {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 70; left: 310; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
.gatchina {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 400; left: 330; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
.volosovo {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 370; left: 210; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
.kingisepp {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 160; left: 100; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
```

А следующий (который с такими же свойствами как выше) позиционируется в место примерно соотносящееся с серединой родительского div `.tableOverLO` ???

```
.luga {position: relative; width: 3%; top: 1; left: 1; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; color: white; font-size: 30; background-color: #f38630; text-align: center;}
```

Почему тогда остальные ставятся верно?

Вывод div производится следующим образом:

```
// Волосовский на карте

if ($total_volosovo!=0) {
echo "<div class=\"volosovo\">" . $total_volosovo . "</div>"; 
};
```

Comment: Добавьте пример так что бы его можно было запустить и посмотреть в чем проблема. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`relative` устанавливает положение относительно исходного места элемента(красный блок), а свойства `top`, `left` и другие сдвигают его относительно этого места.
Если у элемента установленно значение `absolute`, то другие элементы его не замечают, а сам `absolute` может позиционироваться с помощью `top`,`left` и др., но на него так же влияет значение `position` родительского элемента. Как в данном примере, если бы у `container` не было бы `position`, то `absolute` позиционировался относительно окна браузера или другого родительского элемента с `position`.

Вам нужно подробнее изучить позиционирование, так как там есть и другие свойства.

**UPD.** Исправьте ошибки в css, добавьте единицы измерения для `width:1156; height:822;`, `top: 70; left: 310;`, `font-size: 30;` и других.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 25px
}

.default {
  margin-right: 25px
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 10px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block default">
    Default
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block relative">
      Relative
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block absolute">
    Absolute
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я так как вы написали и понимаю теорию. Относительно вашего примера: Представьте что ваш первый блок с текстом relative позиционируется относительно красного. А следующий блок (у меня их несколько) с ТАКИМ ЖЕ кодом только разные top и left вдруг позиционируется относительно Default. У меня так выходит

Comment: @musorgsky, тогда добавьте рабочий пример который будет отображать вашу проблему

Comment: сейчас попробую. Спасибо

Comment: Я исправил по вашим замечаниям, но основная проблема не ушла

Comment: @musorgsky, добавьте нормальный пример который можно запустить и он будет отображать проблему, сейчас я уже не пойму что вы хотите и что вас не устраивает.